# The particular URL created date and updated date

Tags: java, jsoup

How to get publication date of an URL or link from a web page ?
for example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit ( this is my question link i posted today so it should show today date after that if any one answered to my question it should show that answered date and time).
Thank Q

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is any way to find out publish date & time from any url/link only, until you are keeping record of the current/publish date & time for any post on your database. you should maintain a database where you should keep the publish date & time for each post.